# How to add extra meta data to PNG?

Tags: php, image, png, image-manipulation, file-manipulation

is there a way to add some extra metadata to a PNG file and then retrieve it with PHP ?

like Comment field.

Comment: Are you talking about image metadata, such as a comment field? `stat` doesn't have anything to do with that, or PNG files: `stat` gets information on the file, such as size, times, etc.

Comment: @Thanatos: yes like comment field and how to add extra fields, I know stat only output the file size and some other information i was thinking if some how to add some extra data to it.

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190236/how-can-i-read-png-metadata-from-php

Comment: some program like [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel/) is a handy php exif manipulation library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add metadata to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462236/how-can-i-add-metadata-to-an-image)

Answer (score 8):

If you have ImageMagick installed, it comes with two utilities: mogrify and identify.

To add comments:

```
$ mogrify.exe -comment "My test comment" plogo.png
```

To retrieve comments:

```
$ identify.exe -verbose plogo.png  | grep -i "comment:"
    comment: My test comment
```

I don't know if mogrify/identify functions are available as PHP libraries, but you can always use the php `system` command.

Comment: thanks for you answer but i think Imagmagic is a bit expansive for the what I wanna do.