# Does PNG support metadata fields like Author, Camera Model, etc?

Tags: png, metadata, jpeg, exif

When I click on the image>property>details of a PNG image in Windows many fields are missing compared to a JPEG file. Are these fields supported in PNG?  If so, how would they be added in a PNG file programmatically?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497206/how-to-add-extra-meta-data-to-png

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PNG has no EXIF chunk. Thus EXIF metadata will get lost if you convert from JPEG into PNG.

However Adobe has made [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) for storing all kinds of metadata. So that you can convert between JPEG and PNG while preserving metadata.

Comment: As of PNG 1.2 version 1.5 EXIF [has been specified](http://ftp-osl.osuosl.org/pub/libpng/documents/pngext-1.5.0.html#C.eXIf).

Answer (score 53):

section 11.3.4.2 of the PNG spec gives a list of pre-defined meta tags (keywords)

http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo

you can add as many other meta tags/fields as you would like.

as for how, programmatically, that depends on the language you're using!

Comment: This was very useful for me in figuring out how to determine whether a PNG image was rotated a la EXIF. In other words, I can't reliably do so... it's good that I didn't bang my head against the wall for too long.

Comment: Unfortunately some image editors (like Corel Photo Paint and The Gimp) decided to completely ignore these text chunks, so if you open a PNG in these image editors, the information is not visible and will be lost if you save the image again.

Comment: Waruyama, GIMP preserves metadata in JPEG files, much more so than other image editors I've used, but I can't vouch for how it handles metadata in other file formats.