# Transfer metadata between files

Tags: image, pdf, png, metadata

I am converting many .pdf graphics into .png and I want to keep the metadata of the .pdf files, e.g., *Author*, *Creator*, *Title*, and so on, in the .png.

Is there any way to transfer the metadata from a .pdf into a .png?
Or more generally from a file into another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most practical and powerful possibility [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), an application for Linux, MacOS, and Windows.

You can transfer **all** metadata tags from one file into another **preserving name** and for **any file format**.

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile <source-file> <target-file>
```

For example, here I transfer the metadata from a .pdf to a .png

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile mysource.pdf mytarget.png
```

**Filtering tags:**
You can also choose the tags to be transferred. For example, if I only want to transfer `title`, `author`, and `creator`, I set the option `-<tag>`

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile mysource.pdf -title -author -creator mytarget.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a version with *Unix* commands for the particular case *PDF->PNG* (it may work for other target pictures formats). Maybe similar commands are available in *Windows*.

The method consists of two steps that are piped:

1. Get the metadata of a .pdf file

   ```
   pdfinfo myfile.pdf
   ```
2. Get this metadata into the .png file. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113314/does-png-support-metadata-fields-like-author-camera-model-etc) for more information)

   ```
   mogrify -comment "my metadata" myfile.png
   ```

I found that .png files do not have such an easy metadata managing as .pdf, therefore, I just used `mogrify` a command of *ImageMagick* that inserts data as a "comment" in the image. This comment can be retrieved by running `identify.exe -verbose plogo.png  | grep -i "comment:"` or just `identify.exe -verbose plogo.png`

Now as pipe in Unix works like that:

```
  pdfinfo myfile.pdf | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -I metadata mogrify -comment "metadata" myfile.png
```

Note: the `tr '\n' ' '` pipe transforms the line breaks in spaces, so that the whole metadata of the pdf can be inputed as a one-line string into the .png

If you want to select only certain entries of the metadata, you can use `grep` command to filter. For example, here we extract `title`, `author`, and `creator` of the whole .pdf metadata.

```
  pdfinfo myfile.pdf | grep -i 'title\|author\|creator' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -I metadata mogrify -comment "metadata" myfile.png
```