# Add metadata to PNG image using PHP

Tags: php, database, image, png, metadata

Is there a way to add metadata (such as keywords) to several png images using php? I have stored the images in my database, and I want to do the same with their corresponding keywords, but I haven't found any helpful suggestions using php yet. Thanks

image.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Upload Images</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <form action="tags.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <p>Select Image (one or multiple):</p>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="536870912"/>
  <input type="file" name="image[]" accept="image/png" accept="image/jpg" accept="image/jpeg" accept="image/gif" multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit" />

 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

tags.php (Raptor's answer)

```html
<?php
include('../config.php');

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("C:/xampp/htdocs/cmanager/uploads");
$image->setImageProperty('keywords', 'Imagick');

print($image->getImageProperty('keywords'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need ImageMagick's [setImageProperty()](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageproperty.php) help to achieve your goal.

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(300, 200, "black"); // or load your PNG into Imagick

$image->setImageProperty('keywords', 'Imagick');
echo $image->getImageProperty('keywords');
?>
```

Require PHP to compile against ImageMagick 6.3.2+.

Alternatively, you can parse the PNG's metadata with the codes shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190438/188331). Try it out.

Last, if you intend to edit EXIF data instead, you can use the [EXIF functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Raptor. How can I compile PHP against ImageMagick 6.3.2+?

Comment: You can find the installation instructions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php).

Comment: I followed the instructions for Windows installation, and every time I run the above code, I get a message " Class 'Imagick' not found". I also followed this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20599861/5945369], but still the same problem. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you restart your web server? You can always check whether `ImageMagick` is installed & enabled via `phpinfo()`

Comment: Yes it works now, but I have 2 issues: instead of adding a new picture, I want it to choose a picture from the directory they are stored. So instead of `$image ->newImage(300, 200, "black");`, I tried `$image->readImage("C:/xampp/htdocs/cmanager/uploads");`, but no luck. It seems I have to choose a specific picture everytime I run the code, which makes no sense. Also, I am not sure how exactly Imagick could help and what it would print regarding the tags.

Comment: You can always use a `<input type="file">` to pick a file and form submit the script via multipart POST file upload.

Comment: Yes, I have done this already, but I still get this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `C:/xampp/htdocs/cmanager/uploads/' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/550' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmanager\tags.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cmanager\tags.php(22): Imagick->readimage('C:/xampp/htdocs...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmanager\tags.php on line 22

Comment: From the exception, your script didn't read the file at all. You're reading the folder `uploads/` instead. Double check your code.

Comment: I added the code in the question, so that it is more clear. :)

Comment: Your code does not make sense at all. You're not reading the `$_FILES`. Also, the HTML syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Hi Raptor, I am also looking at solutions to this same issue as the OP, I have read your answer and am curious if you know the type of MetaData that ImageMagick can edit as I read there are various metadata formts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18688718/3536236

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can [set PNG metadata in pure PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541839/496804) (example is about how to set a **pHYs** chunk).