# Referencing files in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a photo management system using PHP, I need to apply tags on photos and to do so I have the tags stored in a MySQL table now I need to somehow attach them to the files.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to identify the files in order to reference them in the database, the file names are not unique (multiple folders might contain a file with the same path). path + filename also creates problems since the files might be moved outside the program (e.g. using ftp) and then the reference is lost.

Comment: One thing that you can't control is people moving files, they can also move your php files, then nothing will work either. You can save images with certain names and certain paths that you can store to a database and recal later.

Comment: There is no way people could move any of the php files, application and storage are in different servers and access is restricted within user's own folder. In any case this is not what I am asking, essentially what I am trying to accomplish here is to create a unique identifier for each file that does not depend on storage location.

Comment: Ok, in your case you can't, anyway. You should look into [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). To solve your problem with the files being removed, you could search for it that way, throughout scanning the directories to wich you allow users to put files. You can easily check if the file is still in place.

Comment: In this case this wont work. For example image1.jpg that has a tag "Kitten" is moved from folder A to folder B needs to retain its tag. Using scandir I can identify that the file is removed from folder A but I wont know that it is the same file that is now in folder B in order to retain the tag.

Comment: The file movement can't be controlled when you let them in the folders, it's as easy as that. To find files though, `scandir` is perfect.

Comment: File movement wont be controled, users need and should be able to move files around. I just need a way to uniquely identify each file so that I can attach the tags to them

Comment: You could add a `meta` tag to the file, which is not 100% clean. It would do the job, here is a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462236/how-can-i-add-metadata-to-an-image) about it.

Comment: Thanx Nytrix, this is exactly what I was looking for! I can now attach a custom id to the image as a meta tag when I first scan the folder, and then be able to reference the tags to it when it is found in another folder.

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help.